# How to get value of unknown properties (part solved already with reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have an existing c# application to modify and need to loop through an object with unknown properties and have half solved the problem with reflection.

I'm trying to populate a dictionary with the property name and the property value.  The code is below and I've given a description of what I need in between the ***s

This is an MVC5 project

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> StoreUserDetails ()
    {      
      var userDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      foreach (var userItem in UserItems)
      {
        var theType = userItem.GetType();
        var theProperties = theType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in theProperties)
        {
          userDetails.Add(property.Name, ***value of userItem property with this property name***);
        }
      }      
      return userDetails;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you can do it. (by the way, your code might error out on "dictionary key not being unique" since the second userItem will try to add the same property name to the dictionary. you might need a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`)

```
        foreach (var property in theProperties)
        {
            // gets the value of the property for the instance.
            // be careful of null values.
            var value = property.GetValue(userItem);

            userDetails.Add(property.Name, value == null ? null : value.ToString());
        }
```

and by the way, if you're in MVC context, you could take a reference to System.Web.Routing and use the following snippet.

```
foreach (var userItem in UserItems)
{
 // RVD is provided by routing framework and it gives a dictionary 
 // of the object property names and values, without us doing 
 // anything funky. 
 var userItemDictionary= new RouteValueDictionary(userItem);
}
```

Comment: @B.K. property.GetValue will return an object. we cannot add that directly to the Dictionary since a string value is expected. hence the null check. please look at the dictionary definition. it expects a string value. please let me know if i am missing something. glad to correct myself.

Comment: Thanks that works, and you're right about the dictionary.  I'll use the list instead.

Comment: cool. if you use a list, you might not know what property corresponds to what userItem. e.g. if there are 2 userItems, then you'll have say, two 'Name' properties, not knowing if it belongs to userItem 1  or 2. a workaround for this is to use Dictionary like your original thinking, but when you add the key, add it as (property.Name + "[" + index + "]") so that you get the index of the user item. this will give you a dictionary where all [0] keys belong to userItem1 and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Example**

```
property.GetValue(userItem, null);
```

**Syntax**

```
public virtual Object GetValue(
    Object obj,
    Object[] index
)
```

**Parameters**

`obj`
Type: `System.Object`
The object whose property value will be returned.

`index`
Type: `System.Object[]`
Optional index values for indexed properties. The indexes of indexed properties are zero-based. This value should be **null** for non-indexed properties.

**Return Value**

Type: `System.Object`
The property value of the specified object.

Comment: adding more details about `property.GetValue`, you need to pass userItem as first parameter to tell compiler from which reference variable data need to be looked up.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
foreach (var property in theProperties)
{
  var userItemVal = property.GetValue(userItem, null);
  userDetails.Add(property.Name, userItemVal.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Any additional details/explanation would be helpful.